# How to implement internet radio using java

Tags: java, android

How to implement internet radio using java?
Is there any Java APIs for this?

I want to make a internet radio using Android / java. But I am not getting any APIs how to connect or how to receive the channel information for streaming the audio.

Please help me how to create that same and provide some code/API for that.

Comment: You should elaborate a little more as to what you want to do. You're giving too few information for people to help you.

Comment: @skaffman: Good question. I'll vote to reopen anyway, because this might turn into a good question, if the OP gives some more details.

Comment: Uh ... guys? Aren't you a bit harsh here? How about a few general links how Internet radios work instead of simply closing the question?

Comment: It's been a day, and there's been no clarification. Voting to close as not a real question.

Comment: Ok, it seems he clarified by creating a duplicate question, which was closed. I've added the extra text from that question to this one. If I could un-vote-to-close, I would.

Answer (score 3):

[Cidero](http://www.cidero.com/radioServer.html) is a Internet Radio server implemented in Java. This should get you started.

Update: The project seems to be down. I've found this github repo with a "cidero" project which seems to be the same but I'm not sure whether they are related: http://repo.or.cz/w/learning-java-upnp.git/tree/HEAD:/cidero

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled on this question through the related-questions side bar... Noticed that the cidero link was out of date.  I just suggested an answer on a similar thread for use of Android's MediaPlayer object; [How to play online radio in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625547/how-to-play-online-radio-in-android/4626870#4626870)